# How to replace generic-release with fedora-release?

Tags: fedora, yum

Due to some accidental eclecticism in my repository list, the package `fedora-release` was uninstalled from my machine (a Fedora 21 laptop) and replaced with `generic-release`.

I can't seem to be able to remove it, however:

```
[root@linuxbox ~]# yum remove generic-release
(...)
Error: Trying to remove "systemd", which is protected
```

and neither to install the fedora package:

```
[root@linuxbox ~]# yum install fedora-release
Loaded plugins: langpacks
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package fedora-release.noarch 0:21-2 will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: generic-release-21-7.noarch conflicts fedora-release
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: generic-release conflicts with fedora-release-21-2.noarch
```

How to replace `generic-release` with `fedora-release`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
yum swap generic-release fedora-release
```

or you can try with:

```
yum shell
> remove generic-release
> install fedora-release
> run
```

if it does not work may be you can download correct `rpm` packages `fedora-release` `fedora-release-notes` and run:

```
rpm -e --no-deps generic-release generic-release-notes
rpm -ihv fedora-release-*
```